# Receiving "syntax error, unexpected '<'" in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

This is my script:

```
function Secu($variable)

{
$variable = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(nl2br(trim($variable)))));
return $variable;
}
function Redi($lien)
{
echo <script type="text/javascript">document.location.href=\.$lien.='/index.php';</script>  ;
function PassHash($mdp_hashed)
{
$mdp_hashed = Secu(md5($mdp_hashed));
return $mdp_hashed;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
$pseudo = Secu($_SESSION['username']);
$sql_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ".$pseudo." LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
$row_user = mysql_num_rows($sql_user);
}
```

I am getting this:

> ERROR: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: Strings need to be wrapped in quotes. That is basic PHP.

Comment: Kudos for using real_escape_string, but you should NOT be doing the whole htmlspecialchars/stripslashes business. Escaping is a targetted business - unless you can ABSOLUTELY guarantee that the data you're running through Secu() will never be used in anything EXCEPT an html context, then the extra steps you're doing are pointless, and in some cases, dangerous,.

Answer (score 1):

PHP cannot parse line 10 of your code. You want to enclose your argument to echo function in the double quotes, as well as escape backslash, like this:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href=\\".$lien."=/index.php';</script>" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem happens in the line:

```
echo <script type="text/javascript">document.location.href=\.$lien.='/index.php';</script>  ;
```

You need to put the string in quotes - so it becomes

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.location.href=\\".$lien."='/index.php';</script>"  ;
```

There may be other errors...

Comment: IT SAYS:Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'a8004576'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/a8004576/public_html/global.php on line 25

Comment: Sorry to hear you still have trouble. Can you update your question - show the fix that you have applied, the error that goes away, what the string looks like that you are passing to the query, and the line in which the error occurs. Think about what we (folks trying to help you) know about your problem - and ask yourself "if I knew only what I told them, would I have enough to fix this?" It is impossible to give you any advice otherwise. Clairvoyance is not one of my skills.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to put quotes around the string you are trying to echo!

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.location.href=\.$lien.='/index.php';</script>';
```